# Cleaning Chatbot Chat data Python

Tags: python

I have a chatbot data Something like this. I want to retrieve the customer data.

`Chat Started: Tuesday March 12 2022 12:00:00 Chatbot: How may I assist you ( 5s ) Chatbot: {Ask about product, ask about Product features}  Customer1: Product Features Chatbot: {Ask about on the Color, Ask about usages} Customer1: How can I use the Product when travelling Chatbot: You can use this Product XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.  Chatbot: Is this helpful Chatbot: {"Yes" "No" "Return to MainMenu"} Customer1: Yes`

If I have this Chat, I want to extract only Customer Conversation

`Customer1: {'Product Features', 'How can I use the Product when travelling', 'Yes'} Time: {'12-Mar-2022 12:00:00'}`

The chatbot conversation is in pure text without any format (I did the format).

Any faster way of retrieving will be really helpful. Since I have to hover through millions of Chat records.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Looping/String functions is one thing I tried. But its taking lot of time

Comment: post your code and also original format of the string

Comment: Chat Started: Tuesday March 12 2022 12:00:00 Chatbot: How may I assist you ( 5s ) Chatbot: {Ask about product, ask about Product features}  Customer1: Product Features Chatbot: {Ask about on the Color, Ask about usages} Customer1: How can I use the Product when travelling Chatbot: You can use this Product XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.  Chatbot: Is this helpful Chatbot: {"Yes" "No" "Return to MainMenu"} Customer1: Yes